# Python vectorization library?

Tags: python, vectorization

I'm creating some Starcraft mapping tools. Starcraft map contains many things, such as tilemap, unit placement or fog of war layer. Unit placements are represented by units[], with each entry having attribute 'hitpoint' (0~100%). Fog of war is represented by fog[x, y][player]. (Array of booleans)

Now suppose I want to set every unit's hitpoint to 50%. I just can write

```
for obj in units:
    obj.hitpoint = 50
```

But instead, couldn't I just write like this?

```
units[:].hitpoint = 50
```

units may be a viewer to another variable, but the interface should be kept as above.

Likewise, one should be able to convert this

```
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        for player in range(8):
            fog[x, y][player] = False
        fog[x, y][0] = True
```

to

```
fog[:, :][:] = False
fog[:, :][0] = True
```

(height, width is a dimension of fog of war layer.)

Or like in numpy 2d array copy, this should be possible.

```
fog[3:7, 4:8][1:3] = fog[5:9, 1:6][2:4]
```

Is there any library for letting me doing so?

P.S) I'm a total newbie in python. (But I can learn when I ought to.) Subject is definitely misleading, but I cannot think of better ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not sure about existing libraries, but creating a vector class to do this shouldn't be too hard.

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, arguments):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'contents', list(arguments))

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.contents)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.contents[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.contents[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.contents[key]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        for node in self.contents:
            setattr(node, key, value)
```

You could use this as:

```
Vector(units).hitpoint = 50

# This also still works...
for unit in Vector(units):
    unit.hitpoint = 50

# This also still works...
Vector(unit)[2].hitpoint = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with numpy and pandas, **if** you organize your data into columns. This is true regardless of the language you use, because (hardware) vectorization only works with contiguous data.

Answer (score 0):

For the fog of war I would use a dictionary of 2D numpy arrays, no need to vectorize on the number of players as you will only gain in complexity with possibly reduced efficiency:

```
import numpy as np

players = ['player1', 'player2']
fog = {player: np.zeros((3,4)) for player in players}
fog
# {'player1': array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#                    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#                    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]),
#  'player2': array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#                    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#                    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])}
```

Then modify it using normal numpy operations:

```
#set fow False for all player
for player in players:
    fog[player].fill(False)

#set fow to True for first player
fog['player1'].fill(True)
```

For the units I would leave like that, a list of objects seems to be the appropriate data structure for your use case.